# Create PDF via monotouch on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, pdf, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to generate a PDF through monotouch (iPhone)? I noticed that reading and rendering a PDF has great support in the Apple API - but what about creating a simple PDF "on the fly"?

I want to generate a PDF report and add it as an email attachment from within my app. The only thing i found was a C# package called "[itextsharp](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jayendra/4498/)", but it feels like overkill for my humble needs (I just need to dump a couple of DB tables).

Any hints or examples are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have an example, but support for creating PDF documents is native in iOS and the framework is available in MonoTouch.

[Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html)

Comment: +1 for excellent hint. I actually have a quartz books (quarts 2d graphics, by R.Scott Thomson) but it only shows the exact same ObjC example. From what i understart you can draw to a PDF's mediabox just like you would draw to any CGContext. But i was hoping for an example on how to insert text. But thank you for the reference (!)

Comment: Seems monotouch does not wrap the CFMutableDictionary (Only NSMutableDictionary) ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example showing how to do this in the rough cuts version of my MonoTouch book here:

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/iphone/9780131388291/graphics-and-animation/157

Comment: -1 for refering to your own product. While I love the idea that it's all there, i dont think it's fair to refer to a commercial product (and especially your own product) on a web-portal dedicated to a community helping each other with knowledge.

Comment: +1 from me. Commercial or not, we are talking about knowledge, many times painfully earned. It's a book, not a microwave.

Comment: I didnt know stackoverflow was a book review. If i had time to order from amazon or the US I would. But I found a pdf library that runs on monotouch without problems. Guess i'll write a book about it..

Comment: The code example I mentioned is open source and available here: https://github.com/mikebluestein/learning_monotouch_code/tree/master/ch6/LMT6-3/LMT6-3

Answer (score 1):

This class will convert a UIImage to a pdf document and will hopefully help anyone else looking to do this. (downside is that if those UIImages are large there is no compression)

```
public static Stream CreatePDF (UIImage image)
    {
        NSMutableData data = new NSMutableData();
        UIGraphics.BeginPDFContext(data, new RectangleF(new PointF(0,0), image.Size), null);
        UIGraphics.BeginPDFPage(new RectangleF(new PointF(0,0), image.Size), null);
        image.Draw(new RectangleF(0, 0, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height));
        UIGraphics.EndPDFContent();

        using (NSData imageData  = data)
        {
            Byte[] myByteArray = new Byte[imageData.Length];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy (imageData.Bytes, myByteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
            fs = new MemoryStream(myByteArray);
        }
        return fs;

    }
```